# How to have more than 100 entries in case statement as a variable

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I wrote a case statement with > 100 choices where I am using the same statement in 4 places in a simple query.

The same query twice with a union between them but also is doing a count and therefore the group by also contains the case statement.

This is to relabel some company names where different records for the same company are spelled differently.

I tried to declare a variable as a VarChar(MAX)

```
declare @CaseForAccountConsolidation varchar(max)

SET @CaseForAccountConsolidation = 'CASE 
       WHEN ac.accountName like ''AIR NEW Z%'' THEN ''AIR NEW ZEALAND''
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE ''AIR BP%'' THEN ''AIR BP''
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE ''ADDICTION ADVICE%'' THEN ''ADDICTION ADVICE''
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE ''AIA%'' THEN ''AIA''
       ...
```

When I went to use it in my select statement - the query just returned the case statement as text and didn't evaluate it.

I also was unable to use it in the group by - I got this error message:

```
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
```

Ideally I would like to have the CASE in just a single place - so that there is no chance of me updating one line and not replicating that elsewhere.

Is there some way of doing this?

I am open to other ways (Like maybe a function - but I am not sure how to use them like this)

Here is a sample of the SELECT I am currently using

```
SELECT 
   SUM(c.charge_amount) AS GSTExcl
   ,dl.FirstDateOfMonth AS MonthBilled
   ,dl.FirstDateOfWeek AS WeekBilled
   ,CASE 
       WHEN ac.accountName like 'AIR NEW Z%' THEN 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIR BP%' THEN 'AIR BP'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'ADDICTION ADVICE%' THEN 'ADDICTION ADVICE'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIA%' THEN 'AIA'
       ELSE ac.accountName
   END AS accountName
   ,dl.FinancialYear
   ,CONVERT(Date,c.date_charged) AS date_charged
FROM [accession] a
   LEFT JOIN account_code ac ON a.account_code_id = ac.account_code_id
   LEFT Join charge c ON a.accession_id = c.accession_id
   LEFT JOIN dateLookup dl ON convert(date,c.date_charged) = dl.date
WHERE a.datecreated = CONVERT(DATE,now())
GROUP BY
   dl.FirstDateOfMonth
   ,dl.FinancialYear
   ,dl.FirstDateOfWeek
   ,CONVERT(Date,c.date_charged)
   ,CASE 
       WHEN ac.accountName like 'AIR NEW Z%' THEN 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIR BP%' THEN 'AIR BP'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'ADDICTION ADVICE%' THEN 'ADDICTION ADVICE'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIA%' THEN 'AIA'
       ELSE ac.accountName
   END

UNION

SELECT 
   SUM(c.charge_amount) AS GSTExcl
   ,dl.FirstDateOfMonth AS MonthBilled
   ,dl.FirstDateOfWeek AS WeekBilled
   ,CASE 
       WHEN ac.accountName like 'AIR NEW Z%' THEN 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIR BP%' THEN 'AIR BP'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'ADDICTION ADVICE%' THEN 'ADDICTION ADVICE'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIA%' THEN 'AIA'
       ELSE ac.accountName
   END AS accountName
   ,dl.FinancialYear
   ,CONVERT(Date,c.date_charged) AS date_charged
FROM [accession] a
   LEFT JOIN account_code ac ON a.account_code_id = ac.account_code_id
   LEFT Join charge c ON a.accession_id = c.accession_id
   LEFT JOIN dateLookup dl ON convert(date,c.date_charged) = dl.date
WHERE a.datecreated = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CONVERT(DATE,now()))
GROUP BY
   dl.FirstDateOfMonth
   ,dl.FinancialYear
   ,dl.FirstDateOfWeek
   ,CONVERT(Date,c.date_charged)
   ,CASE 
       WHEN ac.accountName like 'AIR NEW Z%' THEN 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIR BP%' THEN 'AIR BP'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'ADDICTION ADVICE%' THEN 'ADDICTION ADVICE'
       WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIA%' THEN 'AIA'
       ELSE ac.accountName
   END
```

The purpose for this UNION is to return all data for a timeperiod, and ALSO to return data  for the same timeperiod for 12 months previously

EDIT:  Added a missing "CATCH-ALL"
EDIT2: Added a second ½ of the UNION statement
EDIT3: Corrected the GROUP BY to include some other necessary elements

Comment: How do the the 2 parts of the UNION differ? They look fairly similar, except for the slightly different WHERE conditions.

Comment: That is the key difference.  The two different WHERE conditions on the date give today & the same date 12 months ago.  This means I can then  compare the numbers for that day and and the same day 12 months ago in the presentation layer - but running the single SQL query.

Comment: Why not a single SELECT with `WHERE a.datecreated = CONVERT(DATE,now()) OR a.datecreated = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CONVERT(DATE,now()))` ?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ The simple answer is when building this at first I was copying a way I did it somewhere else that used UNION.  The slightly more complicated is that the date limiter is actually quite a buit more complex than today and the same date 12 months ago.  The date range I am selecting for is from the 1st Jul to the current date +from the 1st Jul before that to the date that is exactly 12 months ago. (Financial Year To Date VS Last FY YTD 12 months ago - this gives a comparison of growth or otherwise for the financial year).  BUT as AndryM & you suggest, I am going to try minus the UNION

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One easy way to eliminate the repetition of the CASE expression is to use CROSS APPLY like this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(c.charge_amount) AS GSTExcl
   ,dl.FirstDateOfMonth AS MonthBilled
   ,dl.FirstDateOfWeek AS WeekBilled
   ,x.accountName
   ,dl.FinancialYear
   ,CONVERT(Date,c.date_charged) AS date_charged
FROM [accession] a
   LEFT JOIN account_code ac ON a.account_code_id = ac.account_code_id
   CROSS APPLY
   (
    SELECT 
       CASE 
           WHEN ac.accountName like 'AIR NEW Z%' THEN 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'
           WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIR BP%' THEN 'AIR BP'
           WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'ADDICTION ADVICE%' THEN 'ADDICTION ADVICE'
           WHEN ac.accountName LIKE 'AIA%' THEN 'AIA'
       END AS accountName
   ) AS x
   LEFT Join charge c ON a.accession_id = c.accession_id
   LEFT JOIN dateLookup dl ON convert(date,c.date_charged) = dl.date
GROUP BY
   dl.FirstDateOfMonth
   ,x.AccountName
```

With the help of CROSS APPLY you assign a name to your CASE expression in such a way that it can be referenced anywhere in your statement. It works because strictly speaking you are defining the computed column in a *nested* SELECT – the FROM-less SELECT that follows the CROSS APPLY.

This is the same as referencing an aliased column of a derived table – which technically this nested SELECT is. It is both a correlated subquery and a derived table. As a correlated subquery, it is allowed to reference the outer scope's columns, and as a derived table it allows the outer scope to reference the columns it defines.

For a UNION query that uses the same CASE expression, you have to define it in each leg, there is no workaround for that except to use a completely different replacement method instead of the CASE. However, in your specific case it is possible to fetch the results without UNION.

The two legs differ in the WHERE condition only. One has this:

```
WHERE a.datecreated = CONVERT(DATE,now())
```

and the other this:

```
WHERE a.datecreated = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CONVERT(DATE,now()))
```

You can combine them like this:

```
WHERE a.datecreated IN (
                        CONVERT(DATE,now()),
                        DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CONVERT(DATE,now()))
                       )
```

and apply it to the modified SELECT at the beginning of this answer.

Answer (score 22):

Put the data into a table

```
CREATE TABLE AccountTranslate (wrong VARCHAR(50), translated(VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO AccountTranslate VALUES ('ADDICTION ADVICE%','ADDICTION ADVICE');
INSERT INTO AccountTranslate VALUES ('AIR BP%','AIR BP');
INSERT INTO AccountTranslate VALUES ('AIR NEW Z%', 'AIR NEW ZEALAND');
```

and join to it.

```
SELECT ...,COALESCE(AccountTranslate.translated, ac.accountName) AS accountName
FROM
...., 
account_code ac left outer join 
AccountTranslate at on ac.accountName LIKE AccountTranslate.wrong
```

That way you can avoid keeping the data up to date in multiple places.  Just use the `COALESCE` where you need it.  You can incorporate this into CTE or `VIEW`s as per the other suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Another option I think if you need to re-use it several places an Inline table valued function will be a good one.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.itvf_CaseForAccountConsolidation
    ( @au_lname VARCHAR(8000) ) 
RETURNS TABLE 
RETURN 
SELECT  
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(@au_lname) LIKE 'ADDICTION ADVICE%' THEN 'ADDICTION ADVICE'
    WHEN UPPER(@au_lname) LIKE 'AIR BP%'  THEN 'AIR BP'
    WHEN UPPER(@au_lname) LIKE 'AIR NEW Z%' THEN 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'
    ELSE '****ERROR****'  -- you may or may not need this! 
                         -- If converting every record, then yes, if not, then no!
                         -- Errors should stand out on browsing and it's easy to search for!
  END AS wrong

--Copied from verace
```

Your select will be like this.

```
  SELECT 
   SUM(c.charge_amount) AS GSTExcl
   ,dl.FirstDateOfMonth AS MonthBilled
   ,dl.FirstDateOfWeek AS WeekBilled
   ,dd.wrong AS accountName
   ,dl.FinancialYear
   ,CONVERT(Date,c.date_charged) AS date_charged
FROM [accession] a
   LEFT JOIN account_code ac ON a.account_code_id = ac.account_code_id
   LEFT Join charge c ON a.accession_id = c.accession_id
   LEFT JOIN dateLookup dl ON convert(date,c.date_charged) = dl.date
   CROSS APPLY  dbo.itvf_CaseForAccountConsolidation( ac.accountName)dd
GROUP BY
   dl.FirstDateOfMonth 
   ,dl.FirstDateOfWeek 
   ,wrong 
   ,dl.FinancialYear
   ,CONVERT(Date,c.date_charged)
```

Also, I have not tested this and  the performance of the code also should be determined.

**EDIT1**: I think andriy already have given one which uses cross apply which redacts the code. Well, this one can be centralized since any changes in the function will reflect in all since you are repeating the same in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `VIEW` to do what you are trying to do. You could, of course, correct the underlying data, but frequently on this site, those asking questions (consultants/dbas/) don't have the authority to do this. Using a `VIEW` can solve this problem! I also made use of the `UPPER` function - a cheap way of resolving errors in cases like this.

Now, you only declare the `VIEW` once and can use it anywhere! This way, you only have one place in which your data conversion algorithm is stored and run, thereby increasing the reliability and robustness of your system.

You can also use a CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression)) - see bottom of answer!

To answer your question, I did the following:

Create a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_error (wrong VARCHAR(50));
```

Insert a couple of sample records:

```
INSERT INTO my_error VALUES ('Addiction Advice Services Ltd.');
INSERT INTO my_error VALUES ('AIR BP_and-mistake');
INSERT INTO my_error VALUES ('AIR New Zealand Airlines');
```

Then create a `VIEW` as suggested:

```
CREATE VIEW my_error_view AS 
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(wrong) LIKE 'ADDICTION ADVICE%' THEN 'ADDICTION ADVICE'
    WHEN UPPER(wrong) LIKE 'AIR BP%'  THEN 'AIR BP'
    WHEN UPPER(wrong) LIKE 'AIR NEW Z%' THEN 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'
    ELSE '***ERROR****' -- You may or may not need this.
                        -- It's attention grabbing (report) and easy to search for (SQL)!
  END AS wrong
FROM my_error;
```

Then, `SELECT`  from your `VIEW`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_error_view
ORDER BY wrong;
```

Result:

```
ADDICTION ADVICE
AIR BP
AIR NEW ZEALAND
```

Et voilà!

You can find all of this on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9d652890ae571f010d4b8a9f7f0abf48).

The `CTE` approach:

Same as above, except for the `CTE` is substituted for the `VIEW` as follows:

```
WITH my_cte AS
(
  SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(wrong) LIKE 'ADDICTION ADVICE%' THEN 'ADDICTION ADVICE'
    WHEN UPPER(wrong) LIKE 'AIR BP%'  THEN 'AIR BP'
    WHEN UPPER(wrong) LIKE 'AIR NEW Z%' THEN 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'
    ELSE '****ERROR****'  -- you may or may not need this! 
                         -- If converting every record, then yes, if not, then no!
                         -- Errors should stand out on browsing and it's easy to search for!
  END AS wrong
  FROM my_error
)
SELECT * FROM my_cte;
```

The result is the same. You can then treat the `CTE` as you would any other table - for `SELECT`s only! Fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0709e205f77be73ad9fc93d80fe6aa2).

Overall, I think that the `VIEW` approach is better in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Embedded table

```
select id, tag, trans.val 
  from [consecutive] c
  join ( values ('AIR NEW Z%', 'AIR NEW ZEALAND'),
                ('AIR BP%',    'AIR BP')
       ) trans (lk, val)
    on c.description like trans.lk
```

Skip the union and use an `OR` in the where as suggested by others.