# Best approach to apply a long list of LIKE patterns?

Tags: postgresql, performance, rdbms, pattern-matching, query-performance

As a follow-up to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/206832/3684), I have one of my own.

The original question concerns the use of a `CASE` statement with > than 100 options and the statement has to be used in 4 places - so obviously the SQL is pretty hairy. The OP's question concerned SQL Server 2012, my question, however, is about PostgreSQL.

In my [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206861/34007), I proposed the use of a `VIEW` as a "one-stop-shop" solution - i.e. declare the `VIEW` once, use it anywhere - and this applies for any query in the future also and any variant thereof.

Another poster (@AndriyM) proposed the use of a [`CROSS APPLY`](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/) to resolve the issue which is another solution. The PostgreSQL syntax is [`JOIN LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

I then added a CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/)) to my [original answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206861/34007) as yet another possible solution.

So, the OP now has 5 options:

1. [`CASE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/206832/34007)
2. [`VIEW`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206861/34007)
3. [`JOIN LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) ([`CROSS APPLY`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206874/34007) for SQL Server)
4. [`CTE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206861/34007)
5. [`Separate table`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206878/34007)

I excluded the option of changing the underlying data since, frequently in this forum, consultants/DBA's/programmers are not allowed change underlying data - makes the answers more interesting also!

Obviously, a `CASE` expression with > 100 options (x4) is horribly cumbersome and complex - but when is it a good idea to use `CASE` and at what point does it become a minus rather than a plus?

In my opinion (and not just because it's my answer!), a `VIEW` is the optimal solution - it's simple, will work for all RDBMS's and is permanent and will work for all queries now and into the future should the OP wish to modify the query.

The `JOIN LATERAL` construct will work also as a kind of derived table, which is pretty much what a `CTE` is also. They can both be used down the line in the same query.

**Which of the 5 approaches is better/best and at what point does the technical (ease of use, speed, query plan optimisation) tilt in the particular solution's favour?**

Comment: You left out an option: [Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) can often be a replacement for case expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a **translation table** in a **`LATERAL` subquery**. Demo (Postgres 10+):

```
CREATE TABLE ac_translate (
   ord_nr int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
 , like_pattern text NOT NULL
 , target text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ac_translate(like_pattern, target) VALUES 
   ('AIR NEW Z%'       , 'AIR NEW ZEALAND')  -- rows in order of precedence!
 , ('AIR BP%'          , 'AIR BP')
 , ('ADDICTION ADVICE%', 'ADDICTION ADVICE')
 , ('AIA%'             , 'AIA')
;
```

See:

- [Does Postgres preserve insertion order of records?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95822/does-postgres-preserve-insertion-order-of-records/95852#95852)

Manipulate `ord_nr` to adjust priorities.

**Query:**

```
SELECT COALESCE(act.target, ac.accountName) AS accountname
     , SUM(ac.charge_amount) AS gstexcl
FROM   account_code ac
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT a1.target
   FROM   ac_translate a1
   WHERE  ac.accountname LIKE a1.like_pattern
   ORDER  BY a1.ord_nr
   LIMIT  1
   ) act ON true
GROUP BY 1;
```

Or with a **correlated subquery**:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
        (SELECT a1.target
         FROM   ac_translate a1
         WHERE  ac.accountname LIKE a1.like_pattern
         ORDER  BY a1.ord_nr
         LIMIT  1), ac.accountName) AS accountname
     , SUM(ac.charge_amount) AS sum_amount
FROM   account_code ac
GROUP BY 1;
```

This is easy to handle, keeps the long list of options out of the *code* and puts it into a table where it can be maintained properly. And is moderately fast.

We can't easily use a plain `LEFT JOIN ac_translate` since `CASE` traverses patterns **in order** to return the *single*, *first* match. We can't just join to a set, that might return multiple matches if one pattern is the prefix of the other, like 'AIR%' and 'AIR N%'. So we use an ordering number in the translation table to prioritize matches in the subquery.

The `ELSE` clause in the [referenced question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/206832/3684) resolves to the original value. That's implemented with `COALESCE` here. Basically, this combines the virtues of the top two answers over there.

To top it off, I slipped in `GROUP BY 1` as another way to avoid repeating lengthy expressions (which is not actually *needed* here any more). See:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850510/939860)

#### Speed

Performance deteriorates with the number of rows in the translation table since Postgres is forced to walk through all of them sequentially and evaluate the `LIKE` expression. If that's not fast enough any more, we need **index support**, but the expression is not "sargable" - the expression we need to index is to the *right* of the operator and there is no `COMMUTATOR` for `LIKE`. Details:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860)

There is a workaround, though. My example requires that patterns have **at least 3 leading characters** (*3* is my arbitrary pick). Add a `CHECK` constraint in the translation table to enforce this rule, and an expression index on the leading trigram:

```
CREATE INDEX ac_translate_left_idx ON ac_translate (left(like_pattern, 3));
```

Adapt the query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(act.target, ac.accountName) AS accountname
     , SUM(ac.charge_amount) AS gstexcl
FROM   account_code ac
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT a1.target
   FROM   ac_translate a1
   WHERE  left(ac.accountname, 3) = left(a1.like_pattern, 3)
   AND    ac.accountname LIKE a1.like_pattern
   ORDER  BY a1.ord_nr
   LIMIT  1
   ) act ON true
GROUP BY 1;
```

With enough rows in the translation table (and favorable estimates and cost settings) Postgres will use a very fast **index scan** to narrow it down to the few candidates (if any) and only **filter** the rest with the `LIKE` expression. Should scale just fine. I added the `EXPLAIN` output to the fiddle as proof of concept:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=98f07a328e8262e3ebc6c99d3a8ae869)*